# How to pass dynamic string parameter to a select case in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having code like below.,

```
  'a User Defined function
   Sub fill(str As String)
   For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
     Select Case sht.Name
        Case "str"
          'SVE UPDATE
     End Select
    Next sht
```

I am passing variable as below.,

```
   fill("STP") ' STP is sheet name
   fill("SEZ") 'SEZ is sheet name
```

so that I can update my data in all the sheets by passing as parameners.
but here I am not getting STP / SEZ passed to select case.
Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str`is a variable and when put within quotes will behave as a string. Directly use it as shown below

```
Select Case sht.Name
    Case str
      'SVE UPDATE
End Select
```